# dotLiquid syntax for inline IF..ELSE to Assign variable a Value

Tags: azure-logic-apps, dotliquid

I want to assign my variable value based on following condition

```
var Result;
If(A==2)
   Result = A;
 else if(A>2)
    Result = A+2;
```

How can I write this in dotLiquid syntax for Logic Apps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Logic App Liquid map can be something like this:

```
{
    {% assign my_variable = content.a %}

    {% if my_variable == 2 %}
        "Result" : "{{ my_variable }}"
    {% elsif my_variable > 2 %}
        "Result" : "{{ my_variable | Plus: 2 }}"
    {% endif %}
}
```

Comment: Can this be added to Logic App Code View?

Comment: This is for a Logic App map with Liquid notation, that I thought was your question. What do you need exactly? Implement and IF THEN ELSE condition in Logic App? If you need only that, you can add a condition shape and a Initialize/Set Variable shape, you don't need code.